# Testing for significant difference between coefficients from 2 different IV regressions (Stata or in general)

Tags: multiple-comparisons, stata, instrumental-variables, paired-data

I'm running two different IV models in Stata that share the same DV and controls but have different instruments for the independent variable of interest.

```
ivregress 2sls energy householdsize sqmeters nondetached (investment= built1978), robust
```

and

```
ivregress 2sls energy householdsize sqmeters nondetached (investment= age60), robust
```

**What I want to know is whether the two resulting coefficients for investment are significantly different from one another.**

My first thought would be to use something along the lines of `sureg` or `suest` combined with `lincom`, but I can't quite figure out a way to make it work. `sureg` and `suest` do not work with `ivregress`(as far as I'm concerned), and with `lincom` I can't find a way to access the coefficients and their standard errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - both towards a general (non-Stata) solution but of course also towards a Stata-implementation.

Since I'm not accustomed to posting on these forums, please do let me know if there are obvious ways to improve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this by recasting the 2SLS problem as a GMM one, though I am now somewhat uncertain about the `winitial()` option. Perhaps others can chime in on this point.

Toy example:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. ivregress 2sls mpg gear_ratio (turn = weight), robust

Instrumental variables (2SLS) regression          Number of obs   =         74
                                                  Wald chi2(2)    =      85.55
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
                                                  R-squared       =     0.4483
                                                  Root MSE        =      4.268

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        turn |  -1.297417   .2285046    -5.68   0.000    -1.745278   -.8495566
  gear_ratio |  -.6471477   2.053764    -0.32   0.753    -4.672451    3.378156
       _cons |    74.6892   14.55076     5.13   0.000     46.17024    103.2082
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:  turn
Instruments:   gear_ratio weight

. ivregress 2sls mpg gear_ratio (turn = length), robust

Instrumental variables (2SLS) regression          Number of obs   =         74
                                                  Wald chi2(2)    =      93.27
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
                                                  R-squared       =     0.4720
                                                  Root MSE        =     4.1754

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        turn |  -1.226092   .1904174    -6.44   0.000    -1.599303   -.8528803
  gear_ratio |  -.1820588   1.819862    -0.10   0.920    -3.748923    3.384806
       _cons |   70.45905   12.29022     5.73   0.000     46.37067    94.54744
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:  turn
Instruments:   gear_ratio length

. 
. gmm ///
> (eq1: mpg - {xb: turn gear_ratio _cons}) ///
> (eq2: mpg - {xc: turn gear_ratio _cons}), ///
> instruments(eq1: gear_ratio weight) ///
> instruments(eq2: gear_ratio length) ///
> onestep winitial(unadjusted, indep)

Step 1
Iteration 0:   GMM criterion Q(b) =  949.82073  
Iteration 1:   GMM criterion Q(b) =  5.552e-21  
Iteration 2:   GMM criterion Q(b) =  5.159e-28  

note: model is exactly identified

GMM estimation 

Number of parameters =   6
Number of moments    =   6
Initial weight matrix: Unadjusted                 Number of obs   =         74

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
             |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
xb           |
        turn |  -1.297417   .2285025    -5.68   0.000    -1.745274   -.8495606
  gear_ratio |  -.6471477   2.053753    -0.32   0.753    -4.672429    3.378134
       _cons |    74.6892   14.55064     5.13   0.000     46.17047    103.2079
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
xc           |
        turn |  -1.226092   .1904174    -6.44   0.000    -1.599303   -.8528802
  gear_ratio |  -.1820588   1.819862    -0.10   0.920    -3.748923    3.384806
       _cons |   70.45905   12.29022     5.73   0.000     46.37066    94.54745
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instruments for equation eq1: gear_ratio weight _cons
Instruments for equation eq2: gear_ratio length _cons

.         
. test _b[xb:turn] = _b[xc:turn]  

 ( 1)  [xb]turn - [xc]turn = 0

           chi2(  1) =    0.48
         Prob > chi2 =    0.4904
```

---

Stata Code:

```
cls 
sysuse auto, clear
ivregress 2sls mpg gear_ratio (turn = weight), robust
ivregress 2sls mpg gear_ratio (turn = length), robust

gmm ///
(eq1: mpg - {xb: turn gear_ratio _cons}) ///
(eq2: mpg - {xc: turn gear_ratio _cons}), ///
instruments(eq1: gear_ratio weight) ///
instruments(eq2: gear_ratio length) ///
onestep winitial(unadjusted, indep)

test _b[xb:turn] = _b[xc:turn]
```

Comment: @user211090 Did this help?